# Change Icon Edit in DataGridView Column If The Row is not Editable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created columns in datagridview programmatically. First is the edit column, key column, value column, and is editable column (hide) as shown in the code below:

```
private void InitGrid()
{
    DataGridViewImageColumn editColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    editColumn.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    editColumn.HeaderText = "";
    editColumn.Image = global::WindowsForms.Properties.Resources.edit;
    editColumn.Name = Global.ACTION_EDIT;
    editColumn.Width = 30;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn keyColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    keyColumn.DataPropertyName = "Key";
    keyColumn.HeaderText = "Key";
    keyColumn.Name = "Key";

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn valueColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    valueColumn.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    valueColumn.DataPropertyName = "Value";
    valueColumn.HeaderText = "Value";
    valueColumn.Name = "Value";

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn isEditableColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    isEditableColumn.DataPropertyName = "IsEditable";
    isEditableColumn.HeaderText = "IsEditable";
    isEditableColumn.Name = "IsEditable";
    isEditableColumn.Visible = false;

    dgvConfiguration.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { editColumn, 
        keyColumn, valueColumn, isEditableColumn
    });
}
```

I would like to display `disabled_edit.png` icon or empty cell if the value of `isEditableColumn` is false. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Where would you like to display `disabled_edit.png`? Also, do you mean if  `isEditableColumn.Visible` is false?

Comment: @TonyMontana, yes, when the value of `isEditableColumn` is false, I would like to display `disabled_edit.png` rather than `edit.png`. The `disabled_edit.png` is already added in resources file. So if `isEditableColumn` is false then `editColumn.Image = global::WindowsForms.Properties.Resources.disabled_edit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event that occurs when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display.

Pseudocode in `VB.NET` (sorry):

```
If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Or e.RowIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

With Me.YourDataGridView
    If .Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "YourDataGridViewImageColumnName" Then
        If .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("IsEditable").Value Then
            e.Value = <code to get edit.png>
        Else
            e.Value = <code to get disable_edit.png>
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: No problem, I still can read vb code, thanks, it solved by `CellFormatting` event